# How to navigate from linking (deep linking with branch.io) when navigator hasn't been created yet?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, deep-linking, branch.io

I pretty much followed both react-navigation deep linking and branch.io react-native documentation, and either both are deprecated or just not completely helpful.

All I want is that whenever a deep link reads from the linking, navigate to a certain screen, I'm not looking to implement a listener on a specific screen, I want this on a root path, and is either the onReady (which for me didn't work) or linking from navigator container

this is my code, very simple

```
const linking: LinkingOptions = {
  prefixes: ['agendameio://', 'https://agendame.io', 'https://agendameio.app.link', 'https://agendameio.app-alternative.link'],
  subscribe(listener) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const onReceiveURL = ({ url }: { url: string }) => listener(url);
    Linking.addEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
    branch.skipCachedEvents();
    branch.subscribe(async ({ error, params, uri }) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error from Branch: ' + error);
        return;
      }
      if (params) {
        DataManager.DynamicURL = params['~id'] === "951933826563912687" ? params.id : undefined;
      }
      let url = params?.['+url'] || params?.['~referring_link']; // params !== undefined ? `agendameio://empresa/${params.id}` : 'agendameio://empresa';
      navigation.navigate(`DetalleEmpresa${params.id}`);
      listener(url);
    });
    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', onReceiveURL);
      branch.logout();
    };
  },
```

I instantly get an error due to use navigation, but I really don't know what else to use to navigate to inside the app

EDIT: this is the error in particular

[image: Error]

EDIT 2: I'll add my navigation so it can help to understand my problem

```
function firstStack() {
  return (
    <homeStack.Navigator initialRouteName="EmpresasScreen">
      <homeStack.Screen
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          headerTitle: () => (
            <>
              <View style={styles.viewHeader}>
                <Image 
                  resizeMode="contain" 
                  style={styles.imageLogo} 
                  source={Images.iconoToolbar} 
                />
              </View>
            </>
          ),
        })}
        name="EmpresasScreen"
        component={EmpresasScreen}
      />
      <detalleEmpresaStack.Screen
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
        name="DetalleEmpresaScreen"
        component={DetalleEmpresaScreen}
      />
      <agendamientoStack.Screen
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
        name="AgendamientoScreen"
        component={AgendamientoScreen}
      />
    </homeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function secondStack() {
  return (
    <misCitasStack.Navigator>
      <misCitasStack.Screen
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerShown: false,
          headerTitle: () => (
            <>
              <View style={styles.viewHeader}>
                <Image 
                  resizeMode="contain" 
                  style={styles.imageLogo} 
                  source={Images.iconoToolbar} 
                />
              </View>
            </>
          ),
        })}
        name="MisCitasScreen"
        component={CitasScreen}
      />
      <detalleCitasStack.Screen
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerShown: false,
        })}
        name="DetalleCitaScreen"
        component={DetalleCitaScreen}
      />
    </misCitasStack.Navigator>
  );
}

function tabStack() {
  return (
    <tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused
              ? Images.casaActive
              : Images.casa
          } else if (route.name === 'Citas') {
            iconName = focused 
              ? Images.citasActive
              : Images.citas
          }
          return <Image source={iconName} />
        }
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: false,
      }}>
      <tab.Screen name="Home" component={firstStack} />
      <tab.Screen name="Citas" component={secondStack} />
    </tab.Navigator>
  );
}

function menuStackNavigator() {
  useEffect(() => {
    VersionCheck.needUpdate({forceUpdate: true}).then(async res => {
      if (res.isNeeded) {
        alertNeedUpdate(res.storeUrl, false);
      }
    });
    if(Platform.OS === 'android') {
      NativeModules.SplashScreenModule.hide();
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      <stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <stack.Screen name="Home" component={tabStack} />
        <stack.Screen name="Error" component={ErrorScreen} />
      </stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewHeader: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  imageLogo: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 6,
    marginBottom: 6
  }
});

export default menuStackNavigator;
```

Comment: We don't yet have support for `react-navigation`. Can you share the error message you're observing here?

Comment: @KartikShandilya my bad, post edited to include an image of the error, btw I want to clarify two things, both branch.io and react-navigation mention each other, and I quote react-navigation "Next, you would need to subscribe to incoming links from your third-party integration, For example, to get to subscribe to incoming links from branch.io:" and here from branch documentation, "Now push the view for this URL this.navigator.push({ title: title, url: url, image: image })"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

###### you can use Configuring links to open the target screen directly.

see more example here [configuring-links](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links)
Here the URL `/feed` will open screen named `Chat`.

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['https://mychat.com', 'mychat://'],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Chat: 'feed/:sort', //URL `/feed` will open screen named `Chat`.
      Profile: 'user',
    }
  },
};

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

###### or use `navigationRef`.

read about it [navigating-without-navigation-prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/). 
wait to navigation to be ready and then navigate.

```js
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

function App() {

  const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();

  const navigateWhenNavigationReady = (routeName, params, n = 0) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (navigationRef?.getRootState()) {
            navigationRef.navigate(routeName, params)
        }else if (n < 100) {
            navigateWhenNavigationReady(routeName, params, n + 1);
        }
    }, 300)
  }

  const linking = {
     ...,
     subscribe(listener) {
        ...
        navigateWhenNavigationReady("Chat", {id: 123});
     }
  };


  
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} linking={linking}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );

}
```

Comment: that timeout doesn't look like a good option, wouldn't be better to use the onReady from navigationContainer? tho I'm not entirely sure how to do that

Comment: i don't think that, setTimeout it is simple, and it tested for me in many projects, it retries to use navigation for limited times `else if (n < 100)`, but you can also use onReady

Comment: well, I'm getting this error "The 'navigation' object hasn't been initialized yet. This might happen if you don't have a navigator mounted" multiple lines of the same error

Answer (score 0):

can you try doing it like this

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

and do the subscribe in

```
export const AppNavigator = () => {
  const navigation =useNavigation();
 
  useEffect(()=>{
  //add listener and navigation logic here

  },[]);
 
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator >
      ...
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

this will make navigation context to be available in AppNavigator Component

Comment: ok but what if i want to call the linking from outside, which is a good practice imho

Comment: Why do you want to call subscribe from outside?? As it can only do the navigation when navigation is ready. You can create a function that does all the work in but will have to call it from the position in above code. Or you will have to create some mechanism to check if navigation is ready if not wait a few seconds do the check again... Until is ready and then use a navigation ref to navigate

Answer (score 0):

### Answer use custom hook `useNavigationWhenReady`.

```js
const useNavigationWhenReady = (isReady, navigationRef) => {

    const [routeName, setRouteName] = React.useState();
    const [routeParams, setRouteParams] = React.useState({});
    const [navigationAction, setNavigationAction] = React.useState("navigate");

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isReady && routeName) {
            if(navigationRef && navigationRef[navigationAction]) {
                const _navigationAction = navigationRef[navigationAction];
                _navigationAction(routeName, routeParams);
            }
        }
    }, [isReady, routeParams, routeParams]);


    const navigate = (_routeName, _routeParams = {}) => {
        if(!routeName) {
           setNavigationAction("navigate");
           setRouteParams(_routeParams);
           setRouteName(_routeName);
        }
    };

    const reset = (state) => {
        if(!routeName) {
           setNavigationAction("reset");
           setRouteName(state);
        }
    };

    return { navigate, reset }
};
```

### you can now use `useNavigationWhenReady` instead of `useNavigation`;

```js
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

function App() {

  const [isReady, setReady] = React.useState(false);  
  const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();

  //define it here
  const navigation = useNavigationWhenReady(isReady, navigationRef);

  const handleOpenNotificationOrOpenLinking = () => {
     ...
     navigation.navigate("screenName", {param1: value1}); 
     //or use reset
     //navigation.reset({
        //index: 1,
        //routes: [{ name: 'screenName' }]
      //});
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} onReady={() => setReady(true)}>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

### if you use react-navigation-v5 not v6 use

```js
//const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef();
//const navigation = useNavigationWhenReady(isReady, navigationRef);
const navigationRef = React.useRef();
const navigation = useNavigationWhenReady(isReady, navigationRef?.current);
```

#### you can also show loading or splash screen while navigation not ready

```js
return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef} onReady={() => setReady(true)}>
        <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName={isReady ? "home" : "loading"} >

       </RootStack>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```